# Add the record json pass two null data

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have created a simple inventory form. Form consists of (productid, productname, price, qty, total) after filling the form and clicks add button all records will add the table successfully. When I send the data to add.php. json pass two null data at the top  I don't why this happing. I have attached error below see the first two line show no data after that only show the data what I added. Please, anyone help me to solve the problem.

```
0
:
{barcode: "", pname: "", pro_price: "", qty: "", total_cost: ""}
1
:
{barcode: "↵                    ↵                ", pname: "↵                    ↵                    ↵                ", pro_price: "↵                    ↵                ", qty: "↵                    ↵                ", total_cost: "↵                    ↵                "}
2
:
{barcode: "111", pname: "bun", pro_price: "20", qty: "2", total_cost: "40"}
3
:
{barcode: "111", pname: "jam", pro_price: "30", qty: "1", total_cost: "30"}
```

**table**

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <caption> Add Products  </caption>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Product Code</th>
                            <th>Product Name</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Qty</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Option</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="barcode" id="barcode" name="barcode"  required>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <label id="pro_name" name="pname" id="pname"></label>
                                <input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="barcode" id="pname" name="pname" disabled >
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control pro_price" id="pro_price" name="pro_price"
                                       placeholder="price" >
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control pro_price" id="qty" name="qty"
                                       placeholder="qty" min="1" value="1"  required>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="total_cost" id="total_cost" name="total_cost">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="addproduct()">Add
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="product_list">
                        <caption> Products</caption>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 40px">Remove</th>
                            <th>Product Code</th>
                            <th>Product Name</th>
                            <th>Unit price</th>
                            <th>Qty</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
```

**jquery**

```
 function  addproduct()
    {
        var barcode = $("#barcode").val();
        var pname = $("#pname").val();
        var pro_price = $("#pro_price").val();
        var qty = $("#qty").val();
        var total_cost = $("#total_cost").val();
        var markup = "<tr>  <td>" + barcode + "</td><td>" + pname + "</td>  <td>" + pro_price + "</td> <td>" + qty + "</td>        <td>" + total_cost + "</td>       </tr>";
        $("#product_list tbody").append(markup);
    }



      function save() {
            var table_data = [];

            $('table tbody tr').each(function(row,tr)
            {
                var sub = {
                    'barcode' : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                    'pname' : $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
                    'pro_price' : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
                    'qty' : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text(),
                    'total_cost' : $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text(),

                };
                table_data.push(sub);
            });
            console.log(table_data);

    }
```

Comment: try assigning data with ids instead of find method.

Comment: sir. can you write it then i can understand pls

Comment: `var sub = { 'barcode' : $("#barcode").text(), ... }` try like this.

Comment: And if you are using php then take a submit button with POST method in form and take the post data on php file `$_POST["barcode"]`

Comment: ok thanks sir.i will try.

Comment: sir. after write like that output display blank sir. here 0
:
{barcode: "", pname: "", pro_price: "", qty: "", total_cost: ""}
1
:
{barcode: "", pname: "", pro_price: "", qty: "", total_cost: ""}
2
:
{barcode: "", pname: "", pro_price: "", qty: "", total_cost: ""}
3
:
{barcode: "", pname: "", pro_price: "", qty: "", total_cost: ""}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function  addproduct()
{
    var barcode = $("#barcode").val();
    var pname = $("#pname").val();
    var pro_price = $("#pro_price").val();
    var qty = $("#qty").val();
    var total_cost = $("#total_cost").val();
    var markup = "<tr>  <td>" + barcode + "</td><td>" + pname + "</td>  <td>" + pro_price + "</td> <td>" + qty + "</td>        <td>" + total_cost + "</td>       </tr>";
    $("#product_list tbody").append(markup);
}



  function save() {
        var table_data = [];

        $('#product_list tbody tr').each(function(row,tr)
        {            
         var sub = {
                'barcode' : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                'pname' : $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
                'pro_price' : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
                'qty' : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text(),
                'total_cost' : $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text(),

            };
            table_data.push(sub);
        });
        console.log(table_data);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
                        <caption> Add Products  </caption>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Product Code</th>
                            <th>Product Name</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Qty</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Option</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="barcode" id="barcode" name="barcode"  required>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <label id="pro_name" name="pname" id="pname"></label>
                                <input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="barcode" id="pname" name="pname" disabled >
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control pro_price" id="pro_price" name="pro_price"
                                       placeholder="price" >
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control pro_price" id="qty" name="qty"
                                       placeholder="qty" min="1" value="1"  required>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="total_cost" id="total_cost" name="total_cost">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="addproduct()">Add
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="product_list">
                        <caption> Products</caption>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 40px">Remove</th>
                            <th>Product Code</th>
                            <th>Product Name</th>
                            <th>Unit price</th>
                            <th>Qty</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                      <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="save()">Save</button>
```

Change your jQuery dom selection code from `$('table tbody tr').each(function(row,tr)` to `$('#product_list tbody tr').each(function(row,tr)` it will works. Because in your html two table dom elements present.

It's working check it.

Comment: thank you for your great work sir thanks alot.your are best sir thanks.i recommend you every one.

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery dom selection code from `$('table tbody tr').each(function(row,tr)` to `$('#product_list tbody tr').each(function(row,tr)` it will works. Because in your html two table dom elements present.

Comment: i changed  but same result 0
:
{barcode: "", pname: "", pro_price: "", qty: "", total_cost: ""}
1
:
{barcode: "", pname: "", pro_price: "", qty: "", total_cost: ""}
2
:
{barcode: "", pname: "", pro_price: "", qty: "", total_cost: ""}